# Find object in Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry am newbie to Firebase. here is my sample database.

```
{
  groups:{
    #groupid:{
      members:{
        #userid:
      }
      name:
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

I am trying to find user's group. I am able to get data when I search with group name:

```
let lRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath("groups")
    lRef.queryOrderedByChild("name").queryEqualToValue("one").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        print("hello world \(snapshot.value)")
    })
```

But I am not able to get when I search with user id in members. Somebody please help me to get this done.

Comment: I don't immediately see why the query wouldn't work, so hope someone else spots it. But you're definitely nesting data of different types, which is something Firebase recommends against. I'd recommend creating two top-level nodes `/groups/$groupid` and `/members/$groupid` and then splitting the same data you now have between them. It won't solve your query problem, but it will prevent many future headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example of nested data.

Google provides a good [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure) on this topic. They recommend to avoid this.

Here is a quote:

> **Avoid nesting data**
>
> Because the Firebase Realtime Database allows nesting data up to 32 levels deep, you might be tempted to think that this should be the default structure. However, when you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes. In addition, when you grant someone read or write access at a node in your database, you also grant them access to all data under that node. Therefore, in practice, it's best to keep your data structure as flat as possible.

You probably are going to have another node in your database with user meta-data. That users-node should have a child which contains all the groups the user is in. That way you are easily going to be able to see in which groups a user is in.

If I am correct, this is exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Your database would/should look something like this:

```
{
  groups: {
    #groupid01: {
      members: {
        #userid: true,
      }
      name: #groupname01
    },
    #groupid02: {
      members: {
      }
      name: #groupname02
    }
  },
  users: {
    #userid01: {
      groups: {
        #groupid01: true,
        #groupid02: true
      }
    },
    #userid02: {
      groups: {
      }
    },
    ...: {},
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!